# DataInputStream Confusion

Tags: java, input, stream

How come when this piece of code is run, if you put "3" as the input it doesn't write "Print" to the console but "33" does write "Print"?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    DataInputStream input;
    int any;

    input = new DataInputStream(System.in);
    any = input.readInt();
    System.out.println("Print");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pressing `Enter` on your keyboard appends a newline character `\n` when prompted for input.  For this reason, typing `333` and pressing `Enter` yields the following value stored in `any`: `858993418`.

Looking at the source code for `DataInputStream#readInt`, we see the following:

```
public final int readInt() throws IOException {
    int ch1 = in.read();
    int ch2 = in.read();
    int ch3 = in.read();
    int ch4 = in.read();
    if ((ch1 | ch2 | ch3 | ch4) < 0)
        throw new EOFException();
    return ((ch1 << 24) + (ch2 << 16) + (ch3 << 8) + (ch4 << 0));
}
```

Therefore, we can calculate `any` with the following:

```
('3' << 24) + ('3' << 16) + ('3' << 8) + '\n'
```

I'm not sure why you say that `33` works, because entering only `33` and pressing `Enter` doesn't provide the `DataInputStream` with four bytes, so it continues to wait for another byte.  You can press `Enter` twice, and it will print.  Your IDE might be adding a carriage return `\r` as well as a newline character `\r`, hence why `33` would work for you and not for me on Intellij.

Comment: This is a good explanation of what is going on.  If you want to just read in the number that the user types before `<enter>`, your best bet is to to use [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) to get the input as a string, then use [`String.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String,int)) to convert that String to an Integer.

Comment: Thank you, and OP should just use a `Scanner` ;)

Comment: Ooo, good point, much better to use [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score -1):

Because `InputStream` read as `byte`, not `char`.

`readInt` will read 4 `byte` to construct a `int`. But your input 3 only has 1 `byte` (0x33). Add the line splitor (\r\n)(0x0d0a), there are only 3 `byte` which can't construct the `int`. You can try enter again, it will print.

But the correct way is to read char as char way. You can use `Reader` or `Scanner`

```
input = new Scanner(System.in);
i = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: @mewkie I said there is line splitor (0x0d0a). You can print your `any`, it's not 33, but (0x33330d0a).